# Question about cancellation of auto-renewable subscription

Tags: in-app-purchase

I am developing backend receipt verification. What confused is that, when user diabled auto-renewable subscription, is he/she is not able to subscribe again util expiration. And then when resubscribe, is there will be a new original_transaction_id?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the auto-renewal can be undone any time. Your server will then receive the `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` notification. The same happens when his subscription expired and he resubscribed to the same subscription.

When the subscription expired and he resubscribes to a different subscription (upgrade or downgrade), your server receives `INTERACTIVE_RENEWAL` and `DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS` notification.

If you keep those in mind I would assume the `original_transaction_id` stays the same otherwise I would expect a `INITIAL_BUY` notification.